Fetch the txt file name for each path in a string
I'm trying to extract the txt file names in directory my-repo/text/*/<file_name>.txt by using the following in bash 
echo "my-repo/text/level1_dir/der.txt my-repo/scripts/af.py my-repo/text/level1_dir/another/er_abc.txt my-repo/text/deep/nested/my-file.txt" | sed -E 's|my-repo/text/.*/([^/]+)\.txt|\1|g'
but I get the following output : my-file, whereas the output I need is der er_abc my-file.
Is there a way to do this?

In the first sentence, you say that you want to get the file names from that directory. In the next command, the files are a string to the echo command. I don't see any command which would actually access your directory. Also, when you describe the output you need, it is not clear from your writing whether you need an array of names, or a single string containing all names. If you need a string, how are the names to be separated inside the string?

Can your file or directory names contain white space?

You can use this tr | sed solution:
echo "my-repo/text/level1_dir/der.txt my-repo/scripts/af.py my-repo/text/level1_dir/another/er_abc.txt my-repo/text/deep/nested/my-file.txt" |
tr ' ' '\n' |
sed -E '/\.txt$/!d; s|my-repo/text/[^ ]+/([^/.]+)\.txt|\1|g'

der
er_abc
my-file


If GNU awk is an option, set the record separator to whitespace, match a line on the extension, and print everything before it that is not a path separator:
echo … | awk -v RS='\\s' 'match($0, /([^/]+)\.txt$/, a) {print a[1]}'

Alternatively, also set the field separator to dots or slashes, check for the last field and print the second-to-last (assumes that no further dots appear in the file name):
echo … | awk -v RS='[[:space:]]' -F '[/.]' '$NF=="txt" {print $(NF-1)}'

Output:
der
er_abc
my-file


Use this Perl one-liner:
echo "my-repo/text/level1_dir/der.txt my-repo/scripts/af.py my-repo/text/level1_dir/another/er_abc.txt my-repo/text/deep/nested/my-file.txt" | perl -lane 'print join " ", map { m{([^/]+)[.]txt$} } @F;'

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
-e : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
-n : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to $_ by default.
-l : Strip the input line separator ("\n" on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.
-a : Split $_ into array @F on whitespace or on the regex specified in -F option.
map { m{([^/]+)[.]txt$} } @F : For each element of array @F (= for each path), return the captured string in the match (if any) to the regex ([^/]+)[.]txt$.
([^/]+)[.]txt$ : capture the basename of a .txt file.
([^/]+) : 1 or more occurrence of any character except '/' (slash), which is captured (using parentheses) and returned.
[.] : literal dot.
txt$ : txt string followed by the end of the line.
See also:

perldoc perlrun: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches
perldoc perlre: Perl regular expressions (regexes)
perldoc perlrequick: Perl regular expressions quick start


If you start with find instead of echo, then the task is easier:
find my-repo/text/ -type f -name '*.txt' -exec basename {} '.txt' \;

This will look for files with .txt extension in my-repo/text/ directory tree, and print their base file names, stripping both the directory name and the extension .txt.

Using find and the builtin printf statement you can easily achieve your goals
$ find /path/to/search/dir -type f -name '*.txt' -printf '%f\n'

or if you want to work NULL delimited
$ find /path/to/search/dir -type f -name '*.txt' -printf '%f\0'


A bash approach would be to use an array globstar and nullglob and GNU basename
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s globstar nullglob

files=(./my-repo/**/*.txt)

basename -s '.txt' "${files[@]}"


With mapfile and Process Substitution
shopt -s globstar nullglob

mapfile -t  files < <(basename -s '.txt' ./my-repo/**/*.txt)


Without the basename an alternative internal from bash is to use Parameter Expansion
files=("${files[@]##*/}")
files=("${files[@]%.txt}")

printf '%s\n' "${files[@]}"


This might work for you (GNU sed):
sed -E 's/ *my-repo\S*\/(\S+)\.txt|\S+/\1\n/;/^\S/P;D' file

If the start of the line begins with optional spaces, followed by my-repo, followed by zero or more non-space characters, followed by a forward slash, followed by one or more non-space characters, followed by .txt, then replace it by the string between the last forward slash and the string .txt and newline. Otherwise, just replace that string by a newline.
If now the start of the line contains a non-spaced character, print upto and including the newline.
Delete upto and including the newline and go again.
N.B. The /^regexp/P;D pattern nibbles away at a line containing newlines, printing or not printing upto the first newline until the line is completely consumed.
